# Missing output from ArcGIS Split Raster tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, arctoolbox, raster-conversion

I have a number of raster datasets from different sources sitting in one GDB. In the same GDB I have a polygon feature layer I am using to split each raster layer using the Split Raster tool, the outputs of which are being placed in a folder in TIFF format.

For some reason, with some of these raster layers (and there seems to be no common theme) the process is running, giving me a completed message, GeoProcessing results indicate everything has worked correctly, but they are nowhere to be seen in the destination folder. For more than half of the raster layers, following exactly the same steps, the process has worked without fault. All rasters have the same projection & resolution.

I have tried exporting the problem datasets from the GDB to TIFF and then splitting, with the same result. There must be a property common to these datasets which is causing the error, but from comparison with those datasets that have worked correctly I can't identify what it might be.

Has anyone experienced a similar error?

Screenshots for reference:

[image: Split parameters]

[image: Split successful]

Comment: Asking the obvious question, for the raster files that are not created does the polygon layer intersect the said source raster?  Also, what version of ArcGIS are you using?

Comment: Yep- all datasets have exactly the same extent. ArcGIS v. 10.3.1

Comment: What are the precise parameter values that you are using with one of these Split Raster runs that is missing what you expected to be its output?

Comment: Added screenshots to original post for reference. I have found a workaround- as I am only splitting to two polygons, I can just run the clip tool twice to achieve the same result. But I am still none the wiser as to why the split tool isn't working.

Comment: I'm re-opening this to see whether anyone wants to have another go at trying to develop a reproducible procedure to illustrate how the result was achieved. I suggest that it should involve generating a test image and a test fishnet to perform the Raster Split.

Comment: I'm closing again.  Just flag with type Other to let us know when anyone has an answer that they want to post.